# General performance expectation joins or subqueries in the select clause?

Tags: sql-server

I am wondering in general if there is any performance difference expected between using subqueries in the `select` clause compared to using some type of `join`.

These queries return the same results:

```
select transno
    ,(select profname from professionals where professionals = t.addingprofessionals) profname
    ,transdate, stage, price, value, t.addingdatetime
    ,(select compdesc from components where components = t.components) compdesc
    ,(select comptype from components where components = t.components) comptype
    ,t.journals, nobilldate
from transactions t
left outer join journals j on t.journals = j.journals
where t.journals is not null and j.journals is null
```

and

```
select transno, profname
    ,transdate, stage, price, value, t.addingdatetime, compdesc
    ,comptype, t.journals, nobilldate
from transactions t
inner join components c on c.components = t.components -- I know there aren't nulls
left outer join professionals p on p.professionals = t.addingprofessionals -- there can be nulls
left outer join journals j on t.journals = j.journals
where t.journals is not null and j.journals is null
```

The estimated execution plans are different, but I don't understand plan details very well (90% of both of them is a clustered index scan).

I'm looking for general performance expectations.  Perhaps differences between things that can use `inner join` vs. things that need `left outer join`.

Side note -- I'm only interested in the subquery in the `select` clause performance.  I know that the `left outer join` on `journals` will perform better as a `not exists` clause.

Comment: The answer to your question might depend on how many tables are involved.  The optimizer seems to lose track with a lot of tables (I forget the number). If enough joins put you past that threshold, you could be better-off with sub-selects.  Generally though, the SQL optimizer is sophisticated/complicated enough that it is hard for nearly anyone to definitively say.  (in my experience)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb you should use the second approach with the joins.

This will be beneficial for two reasons

1. The two sub queries with `where components = t.components` can be consolidated. So the work does not have to be repeated to get the values from two different columns *in the same row*.
2. Writing as a sub query in the `SELECT` list requires SQL Server to validate that the sub query does not return more than one row (unless it can deduce this from unique indexes) - this requires assert operators to be added to the plan and limits the range of transformations that are possible/considered.

Point 2 does of course imply that the two queries might not always return the same results. A duplicate returned by the subquery will raise an error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery ... is used as an expression.` whereas if returned by the join it will increase the rows returned. You should consider the cardinality of the joins and whether you need to join onto an aggregated or filtered result to ensure no more than one joined outer row per inner.

See Craig Freedman's blog post on [Scalar Subqueries](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/scalar-subqueries/ba-p/383152) for more about this (and also his one on [Decorrelating Subqueries](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/decorrelating-subqueries/ba-p/383159))

> The assert operator is not expensive per se, but it does limit the set
>   of transformations available to the optimizer.  In particular, the
>   optimizer must use a nested loops join and cannot change the join
>   order.

Comment: This feels right.  But then I wonder about allocating space for actually joining the tables, similar to why (in part) a `where exists` clause is beneficial over an `inner join` (when possible).

Comment: @avery_larry - sounds like you have a lot of misconceptions about how queries are executed in SQL Server TBH. Space **isn't** allocated for joining the tables. Rows are passed from one operator to the next in a streaming fashion. So it is possible to join tables with nested loops or merge join without anything other than a trivial memory allocation. For hash join memory is used for the build input but a semi join (as with `WHERE EXISTS`) can use hash join too

Comment: Whatever you want to call it, a semi-join doesn't return data from the inner table (only a boolean) and doesn't join any columns to the outer table -- which is part of why it often (usually) performs better than a join.

Comment: a semi join vs an inner join that only projects columns from the left hand table has the opportunity to perform better as it can stop after the first matching row is found and doesn't have to match all joined rows (duplicating rows in the result that may then use additional work to get rid of them with DISTINCT)